# External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++

I have a ASP.NET website using C# that calls a C++ method using `DLLImport`.  Everything was working fine and suddenly I keep getting this error:

> External component has thrown an exception. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException:
>   External component has thrown an exception.
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace? Is there anything in the Event Viewer related to this error?

Comment: stack trace just points to the C# method that is calling the C++ method.  do you think it could be because the C++ dll is cached and I have to clean asp.net temporary files?

Comment: Maybe, especially if nothing else has changed on the server. I'm guessing you tried an iisreset or at least recycling the app pool?

Comment: Is there an inner exception that gives more detailed information?

Comment: it disappears everytime I do IISRESET and reappears when I run the method the second time. Seems like it's cached.  What can be done to avoid this problem?

Comment: If you have 'Trusteer Rapport' installed on your machine, uninstall it, and visual studio will work again.

Comment: Can you access the c++ code and rebuild the dll? If so try the old-school method of adding as many "printf"s as you need to figure out exactly what's crashing. Do I understand correctly that the first time it works then the second time it crashes? Maybe you have some statics that are causing issues? Whenever you have external components that crash with no stack or log it's complicated; so first try to identify what's crashing and then why it's crashing. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, exception is originating somewhere in C++ code. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51332.aspx) to understand SEHException. You can use [ErrorCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51332.aspx) property to get the actual error. If its a common HRESULT code, you can get details by searching over internet, if its some custom code then you probably had to contact C++ component author for more details.

Comment: it disappears everytime I do IISRESET and reappears when I run the method the second time. Seems like it's cached.  What can be done to avoid this problem?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, you are perhaps jumping to the conclusion! Reasons for error can be anything - for example, you might be using component incorrectly and henceforth the second call is failing because of invalid state etc. Only way to know is to check from the error code that component is returning - that may give you some idea.

Comment: I call it once and everything works.  I call it twice and it works.  Then it stops working randomly and the only solution is IIS.  How do I get the error code from the exception?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeke, as I said in the answer, user `ErrorCode` property of the exception object.

Comment: It's 0x80004005 which means Access is denied.  In C++ I am reading some files and I think those files are still locked.  do you know how to unload the C++ DLL or how to release all of the locks that C++ is holding?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, AFAIK, locks are held at process levels so unloading DLL won't solve it. IMO, only way would be to close all file handles diligently after they have been used.

Comment: when i try to close the file, it throws an exception:  Access voilation

Comment: Cause for access violation can be many but from programming perspective, the most common cause in c/c++ would be mis-handling of pointers/addresses - for example, reading out invalid address (i.e. using out of scope pointer etc).